# How do I start debugging this circuit?

Tags: lm386

I recently got a small [LM386M-1](http://www.ti.com/product/LM386) based amplifier kit, mainly to practice my SMD soldering. I managed to solder it, but it's giving me unexpected results.

Here's the schematic:

[image: LM386M-1]

The input signal is supposed to be connected to NF (for positive) and GND connectors. ZV is obviously a speaker. Pin 1 is not connected.

Now about the results: When I power on the device and sent a 1 kHz sine wave to it, I get this:

[image: sine wave]

The peak to peak voltage here is around 190 mV.

When I turn it off, I get this:

[image: distorted sine wave]

and the peak to peak voltage is around 1.46 V.

So it works much better when it's off than when it's on.

Also after reading the [LM386 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf), the circuit looks a bit strange to me.

Here's the pinout of LM386 from the datasheet:

[image: LM386 pinout]

So is the PCB I got plain wrong or should I start checking out each individual component?

Comment: The pin numbers in the schematic don't agree with the schematic pinout at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @Frederico I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where to start?

1. Your input signal is being applied to pin 4 which should be 0V
2. Your speaker is connected between \$V_{OUT}\$ & Gain instead of between \$V_{OUT}\$ & 0V
3. Both inverting & non-inverting inputs (pins 2 & 3) are connected to 0V
4. Bypass (Pin 7) is connected directly to 0V instead of through a capacitor (as per the data sheet)

The schematic is clearly wrong. Where did you get the kit from?

Comment: I got it from a local electronics store called „Kelco”. They actually make the kits, so I'll contact them about the problem. I wanted a second opinion because they've been making various kits for some 20-30 years and I didn't expect such a basic error from them.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the speaker should be connected to Vout via a capacitor (250 uF).

Forget about that kit and wire the chip according to one of the schematics in the data sheet.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but when I connect a capacitor, I get horrible distortions on the output.

Comment: Probably caused by all the other problems with the circuit.

Comment: heller why 250uF specifically? How did you get that value? I am in a learning stage of electronics. I think its better understand these things now instead of blindly copying.

Answer (score 0):

A bridge bucket design will fight you on your schematic, its reactions are that of a mirror false grounding.

LM3386 and LM386 are not the same.

Comment: I haven't come across the term "bridge bucket" in several decades of hobby study. You might want to expand your answer to make it useful.